# Blinking cursor visible on texts after voiceover off on safari

Tags: safari, accessibility, voiceover

I am using safari on Mac. Cursor and focus on field looks fine. But when I starts voiceover and after terminating it, the blinking cursor starts appearing on all texts like they are input fields.
To replicate this, use any html page, start voiceover on it and then close voiceover. You will be seeing blinking cursor on all texts.
Is there any way to fix this?